# Mongoose updateMany() with multiple conditions returns 0

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I've created a service that updates all of my `{bookings}` and set the `bookings.status` value to `4` (finished) as soon as the `{booking.date}` is in the past.
Now i need to update one further value `{booking.catering.state}` and set it to `2` (denied) when the initial state of it is `1` (requested) **and** the `booking.date` is in the past.

My code (first snipped is working well), second one doesn't. Perhaps the issue is cased by the multiple condition at the second updateMany(). However, `{caterings.nModified}` returns always `0`. Did i miss something?. :

```
// UPDATE BOOKIGNS WITH PAST DATE OR TODAYS DATE AND PAST HOURS
    const bookings = await Booking.updateMany(
      {
        $or: [
          { date: { $lt: today } },
          { date: today, end: { $lt: now.getHours() } },
        ],
      },
      // SET STATE TO "FINISHED"
      { status: 4 }
    );

// UPDATE CATERING, WHERE THE STATE IS "1" - REQUESTED
const caterings = await Booking.updateMany(
  {
    $or: [
      { date: { $lt: today } },
      { date: today, end: { $lt: now.getHours() } },
    ],
    catering: {
      status: 1,
    },
  },
  // SET CATERING STATE TO "DENIED"
  {
    catering: {
      status: 2,
    },
  }
);

  console.log(
      "\x1b[32m",
      `[manager]: ${bookings.nModified} bookings has been updated`
    );
    console.log(
      "\x1b[32m",
      `[manager]: ${caterings.nModified} caterings has been updated \n`
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying for

```
catering: {
      status: 1,
    },
```

will only match if the `catering` field contains a document that has exactly 1 field, that field is named `status` and has a value of 1.  If there are any other fields, that match will fail.

To check the value of the status field without regard to any other fields in the catering object, use dotted notation:

```
"catering.status":1
```